# How to update a csv file without appending new rows using python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, powershell, csv

I have a power shell script and python script which writes data into one common CSV file. If I used the keyword 'w+' in python script it deletes the old data and replaces with new data. If I use keyword 'a+' it keeps on appending the data which is not entertained. Now I am trying to just update the values in the columns of particular keys of CSV file.

I need help in understanding how to solve it.

```
  Test.csv =>includes =>

  Param_Name,Param_Value
  p_resource_name,res123   #prints from powershell script
  p_tag_name,tag123        #prints from powershell script
  p_instance_count,0       #prints from Python script
  p_volume_count,0         #prints from Python script


  Powershell.ps1=>
   $file_path="C:\test.csv"
   $csv = Import-Csv -Path $file_path
   $result = Foreach ($row in $csv)
   {
    $row  
   if ($row.Param_Name -eq "p_instance_count") { $row.Param_Value = $instance}
   if ($row.Param_Name -eq "p_volume_count") { $row.Param_Value = $volume}
   }

  Python.py =>

   f = csv.writer(codecs.open("C:/test.csv", "ab"), lineterminator="\n")

   instances = conn.instances.filter(Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 
   'Values': ['running', 'stopped']}])
  for instance in instances:
      instance_count.append(instance)
      instanceCount = str(len(instance_count))
  f.writerow(('p_instance_count', len(instance_count)))
```

So this is my codes first I run Powershell which should update csv and then I run a python script which updates the same CSV again with counts.

can anyone suggest a good way of updating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question does not seem very clear to me. When you want to update a CSV file, you have to read it, modify it in memory and rewrite the newly created instances list in its entirity.

`instances = conn.instances.filter(Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['running', 'stopped']}])
for instance in instances:
    instance_count.append(instance)
    instanceCount = str(len(instance_count))`

BTW, note that support for python2.7 ends within 4 months... You should switch to python3

The `instances` variable contains only the lines you want to change (as far as I understand)

`instance_count` is a new list that should contain ***all*** rows in the original list.

Answer (score 1):

A csv file is a *sequential* file. Because of that, you should not even considere changing a value in a field without rewriting the whole file. Of course there are exceptions but it is much too error prone for me to advise that.

The common way is to read the file, write a copy and rename everything on success. The standard library `fileinput` module comes with an `inplace=True` option that does it under the hood:

> if the keyword argument inplace=True is passed to fileinput.input() or to the FileInput constructor, the file is moved to a backup file and standard output is directed to the input file (if a file of the same name as the backup file already exists, it will be replaced silently). This makes it possible to write a filter that rewrites its input file in place.

Comment: Can you show some example on how to write a copy and rename to success.